# Adding text to EditorFor from DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, editorfor

I was wondering if there was any way to add text to a EditorFor by selecting something from a DropDownList.

For example, if I have something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("stackoverflow", "--Select Stack--")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stack, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

My question is how would I go about replacing the text in the EditorFor with whatever I select from the DropDownList. If I was using javascript, how would I go about it? Or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: What type of editor you have? TextBox ?

Comment: Yes, textbox. I've been following tutorials on the asp.net website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with jQuery:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("stackoverflow", Model.StackTypes.Select(stackType => new SelectListItem { Text = stackType, Value = stackType }), "--Select Stack--")
  <!-- Just for demo purpose assume, Model.StackTypes above is a List<string>-->

  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stack, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

     $("#stackoverflow").change(function () {
        var selectedOptionId = $(this).val();
        $("#Stack").val(selectedOptionId); //Set the selected value to textbox
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I can only practice on my free time. Thank you for the answer. It didn't work as well as I thought it would, but I managed to look into other alternative methods.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate your time.